# Getting "you have an error in your sql syntax" error on insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing the error given below.

> "you have an error in your sql syntax "

and my code is..

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $invoiceno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['invoiceno']);
    $dattime=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dattime']);
    $salesitem=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['salesitem']);
    $salesqty=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['salesqty']);
    $salespurchase=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['salespurchase']);
    $salessale=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['salessale']);
    $total=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);
    $itemdisc=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemdisc']);
    $totalafterdiscount=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['totalafterdiscount']);
    $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("alkausar",$conn);
    $query="INSERT INTO `sale`(`id`,`invoiceno` ,`daime`, `name`, `quantity`, `purchasePrice`, `salePrice`, `total`, `itemdiscount`,`totalafterdisc`) VALUES ('','$invoiceno,'$dattime','$salesitem','$salesqty','$salespurchase','$salessale','$total',' $itemdisc','$totalafterdiscount')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    echo $query;
    if(!$result){
        die('Invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
        }
    header("location:SalesPanel.php");

  
?>
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote after invoiceno

'','$invoiceno,'$dattime'

You may also want to remove the space below:

' $itemdisc'